# gdalinfo: error while loading shared libraries: libtiledb.so.2.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: conda, gdal, anaconda3

POST UPDATED to include ldd output see update:

In a clean install of conda following these steps, but having issues. I have done in several linux instances and Macbook pc this same procedure flawless before, now testing on a new chromebook:

STEPS:

Download conda from anaconda site arm64 version
Steps as follows:

```
curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.11-Linux-aarch64.sh
bash Anaconda3-2021.11-Linux-aarch64.sh 
conda create --name gdal
conda activate gdal
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

Finished without issues:

```
(gdal) neavilag@penguin:~/anaconda3/lib$ which gdalinfo
/home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/bin/gdalinfo
```

Running gdalinfo --version gives error:

```
(gdal) neavilag@penguin:~/anaconda3/lib$ gdalinfo --version
gdalinfo: error while loading shared libraries: libtiledb.so.2.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

the file mentioned is listed in the libs folder or anaconda3 installation:

```
(gdal) neavilag@penguin:~/anaconda3/lib$ ls -haltr libtiledb*
-rwxrwxr-x 2 neavilag neavilag 5.0M Jun 25  2021 libtiledb.so.2.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 neavilag neavilag   16 Apr 17 10:40 libtiledb.so -> libtiledb.so.2.2
```

Python seems intalled and env activated as I can check version:

```
(gdal) neavilag@penguin:~/anaconda3/lib$ python --version
Python 3.7.12
(gdal) neavilag@penguin:~/anaconda3/lib$ which python
/home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/bin/python
```

UPDATE:
ldd gdalinfo gives the following out, regretfully the same library  **libtiledb.so.2.2** says not found:

```
(gdal) neavilag@penguin:~$ ldd /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/bin/gdalinfo | grep -i "not found"
        libtiledb.so.2.2 => not found
```

noted here:

```
(gdal) neavilag@penguin:~$ ldd /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/bin/gdalinfo
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000007a4c65e000)
        libgdal.so.30 => /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/bin/../lib/libgdal.so.30 (0x0000007a4acac000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000007a4ab36000)
        /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000007a4c62e000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/bin/../lib/./libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x0000007a4a858000)
        libtiledb.so.2.2 => not found
        libpoppler.so.91 => /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/bin/../lib/./libpoppler.so.91 (0x0000007a4a534000)
        libjson-c.so.4 => /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/bin/../lib/./libjson-c.so.4 (0x0000007a4a512000)
        libfreexl.so.1 => /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/bin/../lib/./libfreexl.so.1 (0x0000007a4a4f7000)
        libgeos_c.so.1 => /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/bin/../lib/./libgeos_c.so.1 (0x0000007a4a4a2000)
        libwebp.so.7 => /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/bin/../lib/./libwebp.so.7 (0x0000007a4a413000)
        libkmlbase.so.1 => /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/bin/../lib/./libkmlbase.so.1 (0x0000007a4a3e4000)
        libkmldom.so.1 => /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/bin/../lib/./libkmldom.so.1 (0x0000007a4a32d000)
```

Comment: `otool -L gdalinfo`?

Comment: otool seems only available for mac, the issue I have with Crostini linux on Chromebook and does not have installed and was unable to with apt-get.

Comment: `ldd` is `otool -L` analog

Comment: thanks for the reference @merv I will update my post with ldd information...

Comment: I went over the lib folder of my env and make a copy of the library to include 2.2 in the name: and that seems to work, seems a bug ?

Answer (score 4):

After checking again all and since that is the only "missing" library according to ldd, I made a "find" of the library, and found it in the envs/gdal/lib folder of the conda environment.

made a copy of it with the name using the name listed in ldd, that seems to make it work, seems to me a but as is not the most elegant solution.

```
cp /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/lib/libtiledb.so /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/lib/libtiledb.so.2.2

(gdal) neavilag@penguin:~$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27
```

Comment: update: make another installation and happened the same even after a conda update gdal, now I did a hard simlink that seems to work but still is this a bug ? ``ln -P /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/lib/libtiledb.so /home/neavilag/anaconda3/envs/gdal/lib/libtiledb.so.2.2``

Answer (score 2):

Here's what works for me. Force use of tiledb 2.2

```
conda install gdal libgdal tiledb=2.2
```